# Reference same variable using two controllers in laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

I am generating a pdf based on user input. I can call the databse and get ALL contract info using all(). However, I would only like to generate a pdf for one of the values. Each contract has a auto incrememnt id which i could use.

Whats the best way to communicate between controllers so only the contract I am referencing is used to generate a pdf?

**PdfGenerateController:**

```
public function pdfview(Request $request)
    {
        $users = DB::table("users")->get();
        $contract = Contract::all();

        view()->share('users',$users);

        if($request->has('download')){
            // Set extra option
            PDF::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
            $users = DB::table("users")->get();

            // pass view file
            $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
            $pdf->loadHTML

            ($contract);


            return $pdf->stream();
        }
        return view('sell.contract');
    }
```

**Contract Controller (user input)**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $contract = new Contract;
    $contract->buyer_first_name = $request->input('buyer_first_name');
    $contract->listing_id = $request->input('listing_id');
    $contract->save();
    return redirect()->route('generate-pdf')->with('contracts',$contract);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the contract `id` [in the session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#storing-data) is probably your best bet. If you need to use it only on the next request, you could just [flash it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#flash-data) (in fact, that's exactly what the [`redirect(..)->withInput(sessionKey, val)` does](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)).

Something like that:

Contract Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    $contract->save();
    session(['contract_id' => $contract->id]);
    return redirect()->route('generate-pdf');
}
```

Or just flashing:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    $contract->save();
    return redirect()->route('generate-pdf')->with('contract_id', $contract->id);
}
```

PdfGeneratteController

```
public function pdfview(Request $request)
{
    $contract = Contract::findOrFail(session('contract_id'));
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a PDF model class with a static method to generate the PDF.

```
class PDF
{
    public static function generatePDF($id, $isDownload)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you could simply call the static method from the Contact controller and pass the required data as parameters.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // ...

    \PDF::generatePDF($contract->id, $request->has('download'));

    // ...
}
```